# PHP/Perl filesize function not working on new server

Tags: php, perl, filesize

I have a problem with a function that doesn't work as expected since I have moved my site from a shared hosting to a VPS (both have the same Linux OS, php version 5.2.9 and Perl version 5.8.8).

When my script store a remote file into a local directory, I run a simple php script at regular intervals (5 seconds) using XMLHttpRequest, this php script execute a Perl script that return the current file size (bytes already downloaded).

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    clearstatcache();
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    exec("/usr/bin/perl /home/xxxxxx/public_html/cgi-bin/filesize.pl $file", $output);
    //print_r($output);
    if (!empty($output) || $output[0] != "") {
        $currentSize = $output[0];
        file_put_contents('progress.txt', $currentSize);
    } else {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the Perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$filename = $ARGV[0];
$filepath = '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/tmp_dir/'.$filename.'.flv';
$filesize = -s $filepath;
print $filesize;
```

When I was running these scripts on the shared server, I had no problem and could see the download progress, but now, the file size is only printed when the remote file has been fully downloaded and I can't see the progress.

I think I need to change something in the php settings but I'm not sure and I don't know what needs to be changed.

**OK, I'm sorry/stupid, the filesize() function works fine, thank you all guys.**

Comment: Why do you call a Perl script to just get the filesize? PHP can do this fine for you, you don't need the `exec` there.

Comment: @ Konerak - How do you do it?

Comment: @ Mario - This is not an upload, I download the remote file using cURL.

Comment: I believe you need to show us the script downloading the file and also the script reading `progress.txt`. What is the output of `print_r($output)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the file size, you could also just call the [`filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function from PHP, and avoid having to use perl altogether.

Comment: I have already tested this function, it only print the size when the file is fully downloaded, so I cant' see the progress, but thanks any way...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused by a different file location. Are you positive that the file `'/home/xxxxxx/public_html/tmp_dir/'.$filename.'.flv'` exists? You could test it with:

```
if (-e '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/tmp_dir/'.$filename.'.flv')
```

Remember that you could use PHP `filesize()` instead:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    clearstatcache();
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    if (file_exists("/home/xxxxxx/public_html/tmp_dir/$file.flv") {
        $currentSize = filesize("/home/xxxxxx/public_html/tmp_dir/$file.flv");
        file_put_contents('progress.txt', $currentSize);
    } else {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes I'm sure that the file exists because when it's fully downloaded I convert it into a different format. I'm pretty sure that I have already tested filesize(), it only print the size when the file is fully downloaded, and this is not what I need to see the progress.

Comment: @Maxime I'm sorry this wasn't the problem. I'll comment on your question, since I'll remove this answer.